# How to set the mainpage of a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, posts, pages

I just created a new custom post type to contain all the individual posts of the event im hosting.

I want the slug for each post to be: **myurl.co/conference/programitem**

I already got a page with the url: **myurl.co/conference/** which i want to be the mainpage of this particular slug. (On this page some other information about the event is already displayed and it will include links to the individual program items etc)

However, i got a conflict now that as soon as i created the custom post type, **myurl.co/conference/** leads to the first post of the newly created post type instead of the already existing page that i was planning to use as the mainpage.

tldr; How do i prevent the **myurl.co/conference/** url from going to the first post and instead go to the page i was planning to use for that? And have **myurl.co/conference/programitem** go to their own posts.

ps. I dont want to change the url to for example myurl.co/conference0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register the custom post type you need to include `has_archive` set to the slug where you want the archive. You also need `rewrite` set to the slug prefix. It's probably easier to understand the code rather than my wording of it:

Your code should look something like this now:

```
register_post_type('conference',
    ...
    'public' => true,
);
```

You need to update it to:

```
register_post_type('conference',
    ...
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => 'conference',
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'conference'),
);
```

You may need to use `unregister_post_type` first, to clear it out, and then re-register with your updated function. After the new version is registered, visit your permalinks page to update permalinks, and you should then have both an archive at **myurl.co/conference** and individual posts at urls like **myurl.co/conference/program-item-slug**.